# AngularJS - matching logged in user with users in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

So I am setting a key in a users local storage when they log in that contains the username they just logged in with. What I need to do is **two things** take that value with their username in it and search through a JSON array of usernames that is being returned from an API. If the local storage username matches one of the names in the JSON array and the second part if the JSON "status" key has a value of "IN PROCESS" then I need to run a simple jQuery line.

Here is the controller that is returning the JSON containing a list of usernames from the API:

```
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService, API) {
  CarDetailService.getCar().success(function(details) {
    $scope.details = details;
  });
}
```

The jQuery line I need to run is just:

```
$('#takeAction').css('display', 'block');
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture above the array that is being returned is "All Current Approvers" and the other key is "Status". And you can see the username (or email) in the local storage matches one of the "All Current Approvers". And even though only one email exists in the array now the other ones in the app will have more than 5 usernames in the array which is why I need to search through the array.

I can create a variable that gets the username from local storage:

```
var user = localStorage.getItem('user')
```

But from there I am not sure how to match it up with the values in the "All Current Approvers" array, check to make sure status is "IN PROCESS" and then run my jQuery line.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a basic for loop will get you want you want.

```
var approvers = $scope.details["All Current Approvers"],
    status    = $scope.details.Status;

for (var i = 0; i < approvers.length; i++) {
    if (approvers[i] === user && status === 'IN PROCESS') {
        // do jQuery
    }
}
```

Take note of the bracket syntax for referencing a JSON property that has spaces in it.

Comment: I don't think that is really going to work....$scope.details = details is returning all JSON keys and values. I need to search through the 'details' output find the array "All Current Approvers" and match that to the user in  the local storage. This isn't searching through the "details' output is it? I could be wrong though. Where are you defining AllCurrentApprovers?

Comment: I'm not, I'm just using that as an example to illustrate the for loop concept. It sounds like what you want is a for loop - I've provided an example for constructing a for loop. You need to fill in the details yourself, in particular the reference to your all current approvers array.

Comment: Are you asking how to reference the array in the original question?

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more specific, including the correct references to the array, etc. I think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Nice you nailed it!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use higher order function forEach

```
jsonList.forEach(function(user){
if(user.name == "name" && user.Status == "In Progress"){
  $('#takeAction').css('display', 'block');
}
})
```

Also consider to set user to null if there is no user stored in localStorage

```
var user = localStorage.getItem("user") || null;
```